# Maximum rank of a Krylov subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the maximum dimension of a Krylov subspace $\mathcal{K}(A,b)$ equal to the rank of the matrix $A$ + 1, assuming that $b$ lies in the row space of $A$?

My argument:

Apart from the first vector $b$, each remaining vector $A^k b$ of $\mathcal{K}(A,b)$ lies in the column space of $A$ and hence the maximum number of dimensions $\text{span}[Ab, A^2b,... A^k b]$ can have is equal to the maximum number of independent vector of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument looks like you have the right idea, but it also sounds a bit shaky.

1. First of all, gramatical errors make your point vague: "each vectors of $\mathcal{K}(A,b)$". Are we talking about "each vector" or "all vectors"? It is unclear.
2. Second of all, it is **not** true "each vector spans the column space of $A$.
3. You use the word "hence" to make a pretty big jump in logic. If I were correcting an assignment that looked like yours, I would not give you all points because you skipped too many steps.

Elaborat your answer, make it crystal clear how you get from one step to the next...

Comment: 1. Sorry typo...
2. Assume $b$ lies in the row space of $A$, I guess?
3. Well, I am not doing any assignment, just a random thought come up when I play around with the definition of Krylov subspace. :)

Comment: @QuangThinhHa Your answer looks better now. Still, as a teacher, I would say "but why can't the number of dimensions be bigger?" I don't care if you are doing this as an assignment, I am just trying to help you to write down an argument to the appropriate level of detail.

Comment: Because the number of independent vectors of the column space for A, or the dimension of column space of A, is limited by rank(A)? (Don't get me wrong, getting to the details is great!)

Comment: @QuangThinhHa Sounds reasonable. I would just add that the span of is a *subspace* of the columns space of $A$, so it's dimension can only be smaller.